# PHP Laravel memory usage increase on Direct Admin server

Tags: php, laravel, memory, laravel-valet, directadmin

We have developed Laravel based software, locally tested with Laravel Valet and everything is working fine. One installing on a staging (direct admin) webserver with exactly the same database and code the memory usage dramatically increased.

Local testing specs:
OS: MacOS Catalina
Proc: 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
Memory: 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4

Staging server specs:
OS: CentOS 7.0 64-Bit
Processor Speed (MHz)   2693.670
Total Memory    1014728 kB

This is a basic static page:

[Staging server: 21MB, PHP 7.4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBXDA.png)

[Development machine: 5MB, PHP 7.4.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbFqB.png)

Another larger page (which needs optimization):

[Staging server: 101MB, PHP 7.4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjbOc.png)

[Development machine: 85MB, PHP 7.4.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjifK.png)

We know this development machine is a lot slower but we cannot explain the memory usage increase. Does anybody know how to analyze and resolve this?

The used framework is Laravel v6.18.20

Comment: First thing to double check is that you followed the guidelines for deploying a Laravel app (found here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/deployment)

It also looks like you're using different versions of PHP. I'm curious if the memory usage differences are between 7.4.2 and 7.4.4.

Comment: The deployment procedure has been followed as far as possible. Also locally this had not been done and this is using less memory.

I really cannot imagine that this version difference changes so much in memory usage.The newe version would be worse in this case...

Comment: My first guess recommendation would be to compare the extensions and modules you're using for PHP and Apache/Nginx on each system. Those can heavily affect memory usage. Considering that the difference in memory usage was 16 MB in both examples, this seems a likely cause.

Another thing to check would be caching settings or other things that might be affected by `.env` settings.

Answer (score 0):

Well Laravel Valet uses a very lightweight web server and that is a huge difference, I suggest to configure your webserver to use Nginx instead of Apache and be sure you are using PHP as FPM module, generally speaking, servers with Direct Admin uses Apache webserver by default and that will increase the memory usage of every request.

Try to switch to an Nginx webserver

Comment: Just switched to Nginx. The results are the same. PHP server is already running as FPM module.